# Detect Operating System

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know how to detect if a persons operating system is Windows 7, I'm a bit new and have no idea how to do this. Please let me know if it is possible and the code to do it.

Comment: you tagged this as VB. Did you mean vb.net or is this in a vbscript, or perhaps in VBA (Office macros)?

Answer (score 5):

See the [`Environment.OSVersion` property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx).  It is a static property that returns an [`OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.aspx) object, which has a [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.version.aspx) property and you can just check the `Major` and `Minor` version numbers to see if it is 6.1 ([Windows 7 is actually version 6.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
    Dim osVer As Version = Environment.OSVersion.Version

    If osVer.Major = 6 And osVer.Minor = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine("win7!!")
    End If
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to use `My.Computer.Info.OSFullName`.

you need to set up the `app.manifest` file to get the correct version number. even `System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString() '` not gives the correct version if you have not been set the `app.manifest`

[add an app.manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328739/system-environment-osversion-returns-wrong-version)

```
Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Info.OSFullName)
Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Info.OSVersion)
Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Info.OSPlatform)
```

Output:

```
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
10.0.18362.0
Win32NT
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing since you're a bit new that you're actually using VB.NET rather than classic VB 6.

In VB.NET, you can use:

```
Dim osVersion As String = System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.