# determine the windows OS version details

Tags: c#, windows, version

in the log file of my application (c# / .net 4.8) i'm writing out the details of the OS name, variant / edition, version number, build number.
in the case of support tickets this is quite handy to quickly understand on what environment the application was running on.

over the years i have been forced to tweak my detection algorithm multiple times.

- first, i'm reading the `ProductName` at "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion".
- for windows 7 i had added logic to also read the `CSDVersion` - to check the *service pack* level.
- i also want to log the "build number". but starting with windows 8 (?) microsoft introduced the "version lie". to get around this the solution was to p/invoke `RtlGetVersion` (from ntdll).
- for more details on the exact version number i'm also doing some manual parsing of `BuildLabEx`.
- for windows 10 i added reading of the `ReleaseId` (such as 1903 / 2004 / 2009).
- but recently, microsoft switched over to `DisplayVersion` (such as 21H1 / 21H2).

microsoft seems to keep changing their OS detail fingerprint locations all the time ...

--

this is my current approach (october 2022):

1. to get the semi-annual tag string representation (such as 21H1 or 2004):

   - if available: read the `DisplayVersion`
   - otherwise: read the `ReleaseId`

2. to get the version number:

   - call `RtlGetVersion` to get "major", "minor", "build"
   - if available: read the `UBR` from the registry to also get the "revision" (https://serverfault.com/a/892702/228245)

--

**question:**
is there any *simple* and *reliable* way to log the key information, such as:

> Name: Windows 10 Enterprise
> Version: 21H1
> Build Number: 10.0.19043.985

the solution should also work in the "future" ;)

--

a note to the comments:
`System.Environment.OSVersion` does not work, because this requires updated manifest entries. see: [System.Environment.OSVersion returns wrong version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33328739/1887850)
that's another variant of the "version lie" that i have mentioned.

Comment: Does [`Environment.OSVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operatingsystem?view=net-5.0) work for you?

Comment: Seems like [they actually fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/environment-osversion-returns-correct-version) the manifest problem - starting from .NET 5, apparently. That might be the future proof-version.. in the future.